# Is there a user-friendly setup to reduce performance and fan thresholds?

Tags: 12.04, power-management, performance, overheating, fancontrol

My Dell Vostro 4450 with Ubuntu 12.04 started heating (>95°C) when its on heavy load and charging battery (sometimes it freezes in this conditions). When on heavy load but using battery, it stabilize on 80°C. I also tested it on heavy load and charging battery win Windows 7 and it was OK.

Is there a user-friendly strategy to reduce performance and fan thresholds in order to reduce temperature?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is; install `cpufrequtils`.

You can then adjust CPU settings using `cpufreq-set`. These will not modify fan speeds; but you can indirectly modify fan speeds by slowing down the CPU ;).